# Embeds are not sent to Discord using webhook Python

Tags: python, discord, embed

I am trying to send Embeds using `discord_webhook` but it doesn't send any embed to the discord server. Below is my code. What could possible be wrong with this code? Is there any other way to send embed?

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

async def send_webhook():
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook_url = 'link-to-webhook'
        webhook = Webhook.from_url(webhook_url, adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = embed_title,
            description = embed_description,
            colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
        )
                
        embed.set_footer(text=embed_footer_text, icon_url=embed_footer_icon_url)
        embed.thumbnail(url=embed_main_image)
        embed.set_author(name=embed_date)
        embed.add_field(name=embed_field_1_name, value=embed_field_1_value, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name=embed_field_2_name, value=embed_field_2_value, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name=embed_field_3_name, value=embed_field_3_value, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name=embed_social_name, value=embed_social_value, inline=False)

        webhook.send(embed=embed)
        print('Sent to webhook, discord')
```

Comment: `await ctx.send(embed=embed` if this is a command? - But what do you want to achieve? Why are you using/want to use a Webhook?

Comment: You're missing the async for the `async with`, and given the adapter is asynchronous, most likely you need to await the `webhook.send`.

Comment: The `discord_webhook` documentaion does't say I need to say `await ctx.send(embed=embed)`

Comment: i am just scraping data from a website and sending that data as an embed to a discord server.